# How to restrict Alt-Tab to cycling windows on current monitor only?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, alt-tab, multitasking

I have two monitors, and on each of them I have several windows open. Now when I press Alt-Tab, it cycles through all the windows. I want to cycle only through the windows on my current (focused) monitor, skipping the windows on my other monitor.

Is there a way to do this natively? Or do I need any 3rd party software? (Using a different key combination than Alt-Tab is acceptable.)

I am using Windows 10 20H2. I am willing to upgrade Win 10 to a newer version if needed.

Comment: In *Settings > System > Multitasking*, the option "Pressing Alt + Tab shows windows that are open on", is it set to "only the desktop I'm using"?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. The word "desktop" here refers to virtual desktops (similar to workspace or activity on GNU/Linux), not physical monitors. So it doesn't help.

Comment: It blows me away this nonsense is still the case on Windows 10 in 2023! I might have 4 screens, 1 playing video, 2 running my dev tests, 3 for miscellaneous stuff and 4 the MAIN one for my work!

So when I cycle, take a guess Microsoft: which programs do I really want to cycle? Can you guess it? Or maybe spend $10m on a focus group to find out? But please fix this nonsense!